# based on index of array add items to array in object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am scraping a website and have an array of numbers that I am looping over:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6,7];
```

they correspond to win/lose/draw for different teams:

i.e.

1st item in array is won, second is draw, third is loss, fourth is won, fifth is draw, sixth is loss etc.

How can I loop through these so I have something like the following:

```
const teams = [{
  won: 1,
  draw: 2,
  lost: 3
 },{ 
  won: 1,
  draw: 2,
  lost: 4
 },{
  won: 5,
  draw: 6,
  lost: 7
}];
```

I tried something like the following but it didn't work as I expected.

```js
   const arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7];

const newArr = [];

arr.forEach((item, index => {
   if (index % 0 === 0) {
     newArr.push({
       won: item
     });

   } else if (index % 1 === 0) {
     newArr.push({
       draw: item
     });
   } else {
     newArr.push({
       lost: item
     });
    }
 });
```

Comment: You need to read up on what `%` does, `index % 1` means the remainder when `index` is divided by 1, which is always 0 (for non-negative integers).

Comment: Start with a syntax free example "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
index % 3 === 0; // 0, 3, 6, ...
index % 3 === 1; // 1, 4, 7, ...
index % 3 === 2; // 2, 5, 8, ...
```

Comment: On right track or not, produce the final example desired for better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, using the array methods like `forEach` won't work well because you need to consolidate multiple array elements into a single object. It's possible, but it would be a bit confusing. It might be clearer if you use a `for` loop:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,1,2,4,5,6,7];
const teams = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 3) {
  teams.push({
    won: arr[i],
    draw: arr[i + 1],
    lost: arr[i + 2],
  });
}

console.log(teams);
```

Comment: +1. Alternatively, use [a `inChunksOf3` helper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50473243/1048572) and loop over the results of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your array but only consider every third element by using `i+=3`:

```
let teams = [];
function teamStats(won, draw, lost){
  return {won, draw, lost};
}
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=3){
  teams.push(teamStats(arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2]));
}
```